# What is the time complexity for the below code snippet?

Tags: c#, time-complexity, big-o

Below is a code snippet which contains nested for loop. Technically it should be

```
O(variableFour*variableFour),
```

but that not the case.

```
void main() { 
   int variableOne, variableTwo, variableThree = 0;
   int variableFour = 10;

   for (variableOne = variableFour / 2; variableOne <= variableFour; variableOne++) {
      for (variableTwo = 2; variableTwo <= variableFour; variableTwo =variableTwo * 2) {
         variableThree = variableThree + variableFour / 2;
      }
   }
}
```

Comment: inner loop: `log(variableFour)`, outer loop: `variableFour`, combined: `variableFour * log(variableFour)`

Answer (score 1):

It's not `O(variableFour * variableFour) == O(variableFour**2)`. Look at the inner loop:

```
 for (variableTwo = 2; variableTwo <= variableFour; variableTwo = variableTwo * 2)
```

Note that that we *multiply*, not add: `variableTwo = variableTwo * 2` so we loop over

```
 variableTwo = 2, 4, 8, 16, ..., 2**i, ..., variableFour
```

So the inner loop complexity is `O(log(variableFour))` and combined complexity (for both inner and outer loops) is

```
 O(variableFour * log(variableFour))
```